# Fixed positioned element Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with position="fixed", I need to get the Top of the div with respect to the browser window top edge using JavaScript, I need the top of the div regardless of the page scroll.

I have tried offsetTop, but it returns the Top with respect to the document, not the browser.

Comment: If you mean the literal edge of the window, then this is not possible. JS can only calculate sizes within the DOM. Why would you even need this?

Comment: Is there a workaround to do that using Javascript?

Comment: You could use scrolltop of the document and add it to the top position of the div, if you are wanting it to the browser window and not the document, then it should just be whatever top value you have set but it's not very clear what you are asking

Comment: No. As I mentioned JS only knows about what happens inside the document bounds. The browser UI is a level above that, so JS cannot access it to know its dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

Use getBoundingClientRect(), it gets the position relative to the viewport.

```
var el = document.querySelector('div');
var top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Comment: I have tried that, but it returns the top with respect to the parent element, not the viewport.